# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow-simd, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

Trying to build a project, but facing an error while installing `pillow-simd` via `poetry` in docker-container.

Here is the output:

```
#0 107.3   - Installing pillow-simd (5.3.0.post1)
#0 110.2 
#0 110.2 [EnvCommandError]
#0 110.2 Command ['/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'pillow-simd==5.3.0.post1'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
#0 110.2 Collecting pillow-simd==5.3.0.post1
#0 110.2   Downloading Pillow-SIMD-5.3.0.post1.tar.gz (606 kB)
#0 110.2      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 606.7/606.7 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 110.2   Installing build dependencies: started
#0 110.2   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#0 110.2   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#0 110.2   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#0 110.2   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#0 110.2   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#0 110.2 Building wheels for collected packages: pillow-simd
#0 110.2   Building wheel for pillow-simd (pyproject.toml): started
#0 110.2   Building wheel for pillow-simd (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
#0 110.2   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 110.2   
#0 110.2   × Building wheel for pillow-simd (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#0 110.2   │ exit code: 1
#0 110.2   ╰─> [192 lines of output]
#0 110.2       /tmp/pip-build-env-3oafkpsn/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
#0 110.2       !!
#0 110.2       
#0 110.2               ********************************************************************************
#0 110.2               The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
#0 110.2       
#0 110.2               By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
#0 110.2               or your builds will no longer be supported.
#0 110.2       
#0 110.2               See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
#0 110.2               ********************************************************************************
#0 110.2       
#0 110.2       !!
#0 110.2         parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
#0 110.2       running bdist_wheel
#0 110.2       running build
#0 110.2       running build_py
#0 110.2       creating build
#0 110.2       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
#0 110.2       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       running egg_info
#0 110.2       writing src/Pillow_SIMD.egg-info/PKG-INFO
#0 110.2       writing dependency_links to src/Pillow_SIMD.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
#0 110.2       writing top-level names to src/Pillow_SIMD.egg-info/top_level.txt
#0 110.2       reading manifest file 'src/Pillow_SIMD.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
#0 110.2       reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
#0 110.2       warning: no files found matching '*.c'
#0 110.2       warning: no files found matching '*.h'
#0 110.2       warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
#0 110.2       warning: no directories found matching 'Tests'
#0 110.2       no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
#0 110.2       no previously-included directories found matching 'Tests'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
#0 110.2       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
#0 110.2       adding license file 'LICENSE'
#0 110.2       writing manifest file 'src/Pillow_SIMD.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
#0 110.2       copying src/PIL/.DS_Store -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL
#0 110.2       running build_ext
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
#0 110.2       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._imaging' extension
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingft.o
#0 110.2       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/libImaging
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._imagingcms' extension
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_imagingcms.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingcms.o
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_OPENJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"5.3.0.post1\" -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imaging.o -msse4
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._webp' extension
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DHAVE_WEBPMUX -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_webp.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_webp.o
#0 110.2       gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-msse4’
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._imagingtk' extension
#0 110.2       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/Tk
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Isrc/Tk -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/Tk/tkImaging.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/Tk/tkImaging.o
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c: In function ‘text_layout_raqm’:
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:478:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         478 |         for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
#0 110.2             |                       ^
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:486:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         486 |         for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
#0 110.2             |                       ^
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c: In function ‘font_getsize’:
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:607:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         607 |     for (x = i = 0; i < count; i++) {
#0 110.2             |                       ^
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:627:15: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         627 |         if (i == count - 1)
#0 110.2             |               ^~
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c: In function ‘font_render’:
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:718:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         718 |     for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
#0 110.2             |                   ^
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:731:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         731 |     for (x = i = 0; i < count; i++) {
#0 110.2             |                       ^
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:758:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         758 |             for (y = 0; y < glyph->bitmap.rows; y++) {
#0 110.2             |                           ^
#0 110.2       src/_imagingft.c:778:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
#0 110.2         778 |             for (y = 0; y < glyph->bitmap.rows; y++) {
#0 110.2             |                           ^
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Isrc/Tk -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_imagingtk.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingtk.o
#0 110.2       gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_webp.o -L/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lwebp -lwebpmux -lwebpdemux -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL/_webp.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
#0 110.2       gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/Tk/tkImaging.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingtk.o -L/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL/_imagingtk.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._imagingmath' extension
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingmath.o
#0 110.2       building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
#0 110.2       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/openjpeg-2.5 -I/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c/src/libImaging -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/root/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingmorph.o
#0 110.2       gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingft.o -L/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lfreetype -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL/_imagingft.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
#0 110.2       gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingmorph.o -L/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL/_imagingmorph.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
#0 110.2       gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingcms.o -L/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -llcms2 -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL/_imagingcms.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
#0 110.2       gcc -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/src/_imagingmath.o -L/tmp/pip-install-0elg3rki/pillow-simd_0ac1351c38fa4f8fb42e6e7d2a2cd19c -L/usr/include/libpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/PIL/_imagingmath.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
#0 110.2       error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#0 110.2       [end of output]
#0 110.2   
#0 110.2   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 110.2   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow-simd
#0 110.2 Failed to build pillow-simd
#0 110.2 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow-simd, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to find the solution on the Internet, but I only found a suggestion to install additional libraries for `pillow`… My Dockerfile contains the following:

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y netcat-traditional
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential binutils
RUN apt-get install -y libproj-dev gdal-bin python-dev-is-python3 libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libjpeg62-turbo-dev zlib1g-dev
...
```

Would appreciate any help!